# Obtener valores de una variable jsp en javascript

Tags: javascript, java, aplicación-web, java-ee, jstl

Estaba probando 2 maneras de obtener  valores en de una variable jsp en mi javascript, pero me dan resultados diferentes

PRIMERA ALTERNATIVA

```
//Con esto obtengo un string con este valor "[1,2,3,4]"
<%
String permisos= (String)session.getAttribute("permisos");
%>

//Ahora ess valor lo paso aqui 
<input id="permisos" type="hidden" value="<%=permisos%>">

//En el script hago que se escriba su valor
var cadena = $('#permisos').val();
alert(cadena);
//El script me vota el siguiente valor [1,2,3,4]
```

SEGUNDA ALTERNATIVA

```
//Con esto obtengo un string con este valor "[1,2,3,4]"
<%
String permisos= (String)session.getAttribute("permisos");
%>
//Ahora el valor  lo pongo directamente en el script a diferencia del primer caso
var cadena = <%=permisos%>
alert(cadena);
////Con esto obtengo un string con este valor "1,2,3,4"
```

1. Porque la diferencia en lo que retornan ?
2. Lo mas importante es que usando el primer metodo puedo usar el js de manera externa y llamarlo a otras paginas, pero devuelve [1,2,3,4] (lo que no me sirve) , y usando la segunda forma retorna 1,2,3,4 (lo que necesito) , PERO no me permitiria llamarlo como js pues tiene una variable jsp adentro.

Comment: Es sencillo, en Javascript lo que se hace es lo siguiente var cadena = [1,2,3,4]

Con la forma de arriba se hace lo siguiente 
var cadena = '[1,2,3,4]', por lo que tu segunda cadena no es una cadena sino un array de enteros.
Puedes solucionarlo con var cadena = JSON.parse($('#permisos').val());

Comment: @Ajeno ¿lo puedes poner como respuesta?

Answer (score 1):

Es sencillo, en Javascript lo que se hace es lo siguiente

```
var cadena = [1,2,3,4]
```

Con la forma de arriba se hace lo siguiente

```
var cadena = '[1,2,3,4]',
```

por lo que tu segunda cadena no es una cadena sino un array de enteros. 
Puedes solucionarlo con

```
var cadena = JSON.parse($('#permisos').val());
```